# query mnesia data by where with 'or'

Tags: erlang, mnesia

SQL:
select account from y_account where id>5

Mnesia qlc:

```
F = fun() ->
    Q = qlc:q([E#y_account.account || E <- mnesia:table(y_account), E#y_account.id>5]),
    qlc:e(Q)
    end,
mnesia:transaction(F).
```

I can select data in mnesia like this.
But how to select data by where containing 'or', like this SQL:

select account from y_account where id>5 or name='joe'

Thanks,
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check if there is a more efficient way, but you could replace

`E#y_account.id>5` by `(E#y_account.id>5) orelse (E#y_account.name == "joe")`

Answer (score 1):

Use operator `or`:

```
F = fun() ->
    Q = qlc:q([E#y_account.account ||
        E <- mnesia:table(y_account), (E#y_account.id > 5) or (E#y_account.name == "joe")]),
    qlc:e(Q)
    end,
mnesia:transaction(F).
```